# What happens to other attributes after Django queryset distinct is used?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

On this query set what will happen to the score attribute if I do something like:
myqset.distinct('Name')?
Does it just take one of the score values or is there something I can do to get the average of the scores?

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| John | 100 |
| John | 90 |
| Adam | 80 |
| Adam | 70 |

Comment: maybe try to run code to see result. In SQL you could use  `AVG(Score)`, in django should be special command for similar aggregation functions.

Comment: Django doc: [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/) - ie, `Book.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('price'))`, `Book.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))`

Comment: but you probably will need something like `myqset.values_list('Name').annotate(Avg('Score'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
from django.db.models import AVG

YourModel.objects.all().values("name").annotate(score=AVG("score"))
```